# Unable to import js-search in vue js component

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I am trying to import `js-search` npm module in a vue component. But whenever I do this:

`import JsSearch from 'js-search'`

Above when logged `console.log(JsSearch)` give undefined.

I further investigated that [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-search)

Its `package.json` shows `"main": "dist/commonjs/index.js"`
The file looks like this:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _index = require('./IndexStrategy/index');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'AllSubstringsIndexStrategy', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index.AllSubstringsIndexStrategy;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, 'ExactWordIndexStrategy', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index.ExactWordIndexStrategy;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, 'PrefixIndexStrategy', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index.PrefixIndexStrategy;
  }
});

var _index2 = require('./Sanitizer/index');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'CaseSensitiveSanitizer', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index2.CaseSensitiveSanitizer;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, 'LowerCaseSanitizer', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index2.LowerCaseSanitizer;
  }
});

var _index3 = require('./SearchIndex/index');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'TfIdfSearchIndex', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index3.TfIdfSearchIndex;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, 'UnorderedSearchIndex', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index3.UnorderedSearchIndex;
  }
});

var _index4 = require('./Tokenizer/index');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'SimpleTokenizer', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index4.SimpleTokenizer;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, 'StemmingTokenizer', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index4.StemmingTokenizer;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, 'StopWordsTokenizer', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index4.StopWordsTokenizer;
  }
});

var _Search = require('./Search');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'Search', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _Search.Search;
  }
});

var _StopWordsMap = require('./StopWordsMap');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'StopWordsMap', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _StopWordsMap.StopWordsMap;
  }
});

var _TokenHighlighter = require('./TokenHighlighter');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'TokenHighlighter', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _TokenHighlighter.TokenHighlighter;
  }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

In that file, I see that there are no `module.exports`, but there are various `Object.defineProperty` and few variables starting with `_`

AFAIK, underscores in javascript are just conventions. So I assume the underscore variables should be atleast available in the `JsSearch` variable if I import them and hence it should not be undefined(isn't it?)

So basically how does this npm module even work with `require` and what should I do to make it work with `import`?

(I found this issue on its github repo: https://github.com/bvaughn/js-search/issues/33 maybe this helps)

Comment: Maybe it's a client-side search library and the `jsSearch` variable is being made available on `window`? That won't work in node.

Comment: Its vue js app. so no question of node @Kokodoko

Comment: The documentation says to import it like this: `import * as JsSearch from 'js-search'`

Comment: @rahulserver you used the `node` tag...

Comment: @Rudy which documentation says that?

Comment: @rahulserver Here: https://github.com/bvaughn/js-search#overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here https://github.com/bvaughn/js-search you can find an example of usage of this package

You need to import it this way

```
import * as JsSearch from 'js-search';
```

Because in source code in index.js you can see that there is no export with name JsSearch. So you can't import it this way.

Comment: Damn! How did I miss this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Every npm package has its page on npmjs.com, and on the right you can see number of downloads, version number and homepage. Homepage is github repository. Sometimes on github page package author puts more information, so really useful to look there.